# mapreduce simple function - using python

Tags: python, mapreduce, bigdata

I am attempting to understand better big data programming, but I almost know nothing about python. So I use mapreduce paradigm and practically in python I treat some text files stored in some directory say `mydir`, so that my data source is:

```
global_file = glob.glob("mydir/*")

def file_contents(file_name):
     f = open(file_name)
     try:
         return f.read()
     finally:
         f.close()

datasource = dict((file_name, file_contents(file_name)) for file_name in global_file)
```

then my mapreduce function is

```
#each line in each text file is structured as follow : paper-id:::author1::author2::…. ::authorN:::title
def mapfn(k, v):
    for w in v.splitlines():
        separator = w.split('\:\:|\:\:\:')
        for x in separator[1:len(separator)-1]:
            for y in separator[-1].split():
                yield x + y, 1
```

At first, `k` and `v` will stand for a key value pair where `k` is the file's id ans `v` is the content of the latter file. (At the end I want to obtain the number of occurrence of each word grouped by author)

Now the problem is that when I run the algo, I get a blank array result. Is my python syntax correct ?

Comment: Your syntax is "correct" as long as you don't have a SyntaxError. Your namings could be better and your regexp doesn't work as you'd expect but that's another point. I strongly suspect your problem is with populating your datasource from a relative path. Just print out your "global_file" variable to find out if you get anything.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I updated my post. I still have an empty array results. When I print out "datasource", I get the correct content. Notice that I changed my mapfn function in order not to use the "re" library. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I partially rewrote your mapfn function with better naming and a correct regexp for the split, and added a simple test:

```
import re

datasource = {
    "foo":(
        "paper-1:::author1::author2::authorN:::title1\n" 
        "paper-2:::author21::author22::author23::author2N:::title2\n"
        "paper-3:::author31::author32:::title3"
        )
    }

def mapfn(k, v):
    for line in v.splitlines():
        data = re.split(r":{2,3}", line)
        words = data[-1].split()
        for author in data[1:-1]:
            for word in words:
                yield author + word, 1


def main():
    for k, v in datasource.items():
        for result in mapfn(k, v):
            print result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This yields the following results:

```
bruno@betty ~/Work/playground $ python mapf.py 
('author1title1', 1)
('author2title1', 1)
('authorNtitle1', 1)
('author21title2', 1)
('author22title2', 1)
('author23title2', 1)
('author2Ntitle2', 1)
('author31title3', 1)
('author32title3', 1)
```

Not sure that's what you expected but at least it produces some output. I don't have any hands-on experience with mapReduce so far so you'll either have to tell more about the context and how you run your code and/or wait for the local mapReduce guru to chime in.